# getting the changed value in state

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a project that sends values to a server when the state changes via websocket and i'm using redux-toolkit and I have a state like this

```
const initialState = {
  exposure: false,
  whiteBalance: false,
  shutterSpeed: 1,
  iso: 50,
  temperature : 5500,
  tint : 0,
  brightness: { checked: false, value: 0 },
  hue: { checked: false, value: 0 },
  saturation: { checked: false, value: 0 },
  vibrance: { checked: false, value: 0 },
  contrast: { checked: false, value: 0 },
  gamma: { checked: false, value: 0 },
  sharpness: { checked: false, value: 0 },
};

const imageAdjustmentsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "imageAdjustments",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    changeIso: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>): void => {
      state.iso = action.payload;
    },
    changeTemperature: (state,action: PayloadAction<number>): void => {
      state.temperature = action.payload;
    },
    changeTint: (state,action: PayloadAction<number>): void => {
      state.tint = action.payload;
    },
    // and other reducers
  }
});

const store = configureStore({  
  reducer: {
    imgAdjustments:imageAdjustmentsSlice.reducer,
  },
});
```

```
const WSController: React.FC = () => {
      const videoStore = useAppSelector((state) => state.imgAdjustments);
      const { sendMessage } = useWebSocket("ws://localhost:3000");
    
      React.useEffect(() => {
        // i want to send the changed value only not the whole state.
        sendMessage(JSON.stringify(videoStore));
      }, [videoStore ]);

      return <></>
}
```

When videoStore changes i want to send the changed values to server. I want to know which value changes when the state changes.  E.g. i changed iso value in somewhere using dispatch. I just want to get the changed value which is iso. Like this :

```
const changedValue = getChangedValue(state) // returns { iso : 200 }
```

Is there function/hook or another way to do this ? Or should i reconfigure redux?

Comment: "Is there function/hook to do this?" - Quite simply, no, nothing out-of-the-box from React or Redux-Toolkit has this functionality, you'd need to implement this yourself. That said, wouldn't you already know ahead of time "what changed" by virtue of having dispatched the specific `changeIso` action? Instead of selecting the entire state, which is not recommended BTW, you should be selecting more specific state. Can you [edit] to clarify the use case you are trying to solve for here, and possibly include a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: i need entire state because i have to detect when any value changes in state , that's why i selected that all. Instead of sending the whole state all the time, I want to send only the changing values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no "built-in" React or React-Redux/Redux-Toolkit hook for this behavior/logic so you'd need to implement it yourself. I'd suggest implementing a custom React hook that can compute the difference between a current and previous object value.

Example:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

// Typical "usePrevious" value hook recipe
const usePrevious = (value) => {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });

  return ref.current;
};

const useObjectDiff = (current) => {
  const previous = usePrevious(current);

  const diff = {};

  if (current && previous) {
    Object.entries(current).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (previous[key] !== value) {
        diff[key] = value;
      }
    });
  }

  return Object.keys(diff).length ? diff : null;
};
```

Demo:

[image: Edit getting-the-changed-value-in-state]

Usage:

```js
const WSController = () => {
  const videoStore = useAppSelector((state) => state.imgAdjustments);
  const { sendMessage } = useWebSocket("ws://localhost:3000");

  const videoStoreDiff = useObjectDiff(videoStore);
    
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (videoStoreDiff) {
      sendMessage(JSON.stringify(videoStore));
    }
  }, [videoStoreDiff]);

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```